# How can I export a MySQL database user?

Tags: mysql

How can I export a MySQL database user? I think the user for permission to access mysql.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Didn't understand the question one bit.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL users are stored in the mysql database, in the user table.

`use mysql;  select * from user where user= 'Charlie'`

would give you the user record(s) for Charlie.